# Is Pure attribute useless?

Tags: c#, performance, attributes

I found PureAttribute in .NET source code (System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute) and here is the summary:

> Indicates that a type or method is pure, that is, it does not make any visible state changes.
> I checked here [lowered C#](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

I checked ever in debug mode Debug -> windows -> Disassembly and the code is exactly the same. So what is the different? I found that "There is a contract" etc. or "if we send the same parameters always we get the same result". Ok, got it but if it change nothing we it exists? No performance? No readability? And what is that contract?

I expect get answers for these questions:

- If it changes nothing why does it exist? No performance? No readability?
- What is that contract?

Comment: Are you aware of [Code Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts)?

Comment: Code contracts aren't supported in .NET 5+ (including .NET Core versions). Consider using Nullable reference types instead.

so if I use .NET 7 it's useless, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's useless at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original purpose of the `[Pure]` attribute appears to have been to support the old "Code Contracts" analysis, which sadly is no longer being developed.

The `[Pure]` attribute is [*not* used in any code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute?view=net-7.0):

> This attribute is not enforced by the current analysis tools

Now the only purpose is for documenting the fact that a method does not cause any observable state change - but unfortunately no code analysis tools that I know of actually enforce this.

There is one Resharper warning which is provoked by the `[Pure]` attribute: If you ignore the return value of a pure method, Resharper will warn you. Other than that, nothing seems to warn you if you modify observable state in a pure method or change the state of a pure parameter, as the following code demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CalculateSomething(); // Resharper warning: "Return value of pure method not used".
        ChangeSomething();    // Resharper warning: "Return value of pure method not used".
        DoSomething();        // No warnings.
    }

    [Pure] public static int CalculateSomething()
    {
        return _field;
    }

    [Pure] public static int ChangeSomething()
    {
        _field = 1; // Provokes NO warning.
        return 42;
    }

    public static int DoSomething()
    {
        return _field;
    }

    public static void ChangeParameter([Pure] Random rng)
    {
        _ = rng.Next(); // No warning about calling impure method of pure parameter.
    }

    static int _field;

}
```

Microsoft's Code Analysis will also issue [a similar warning, CA1806](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806), if you fail to observe the return value of a pure method.